# Pi Zero W cannot get to connect to wifi

Tags: pi-zero-w

I have created the ssh file with no extension and the wpa_supplicant.conf file with the following code in it:

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="2.4GHz_Guest2879B2"
    scan_ssid=1
    psk="password"
    key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
}
```

I have tried with both Raspbian Jessie and stretch. I am hoping I can SSH in so I don't need to get adapters.

Any advice??

Comment: How do you know it's not connected? Where did you put the two files? Is the SSID hidden?

Comment: What ip address does your RasPi have? Please address me with @Ingo.

Comment: You could try using gadget mode to see what's going on with the network/access logs. Ensure the SSID matches exactly.

Answer (score -1):

**Enable automatic Wi-Fi connection**

To make the Pi connect to your Wifi access point at first boot, store the wifi connection details on the Pi’s boot drive. `nano wpa_supplicant.conf`
Add the following lines to the file and save it.

`ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
network={
    ssid="YOUR_SSID"
    psk="YOUR_WIFI_PASSWORD"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}`

**Enabling SSH**

In the `boot` partition, create a file called `ssh`. Just an empty file with exactly that name.

**Check connection**

Now, to check if raspberry pi is connected to Wi-Fi, use any software like nmap/zenmap and you will find the IP address. If you do not want to use any software, just go to you router admin panel and find which devices are connected to it.

Comment: I'm unsure but you do not need a `country=` code in *wpa_supplicant* on a Pi Zerro W?

Comment: I'm sure it's not necessary to use `country=` because it never used it. But still, it works fine. You can also configure it afterward using `raspi-config` tool.

Comment: You pretty much just told him to do exactly what he's already done and listed in his question.